# How to find unneeded/useless vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, optimization

In some of my Blender files there are unneeded / useless vertices.
The screenshot shows this:

[image: Vertice]

The vertex is not needed. Is there a way to search the model to find such vertices?

**Edit:**

This section relates to the answer given below which is is a good solution.

I simulated a poor 3d model as show in the picture (The selected vertex is the culprit I am looking for)

[image: Poor vertex]

Simply using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> > *Amount of connecting edges* locates the poor vertex

[image]

The area around it is not selected, so it stands out. In this case I would manually delete the vertex and re-connect the vertices together in the surrounding area to fix this problematic area.

Comment: You can try to select all the vertices (or needed parts), then X and 'limited dissolve'. Have a look at the option of the operator (bottom left) after that.

Comment: OK, that looks like the option that I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter edit mode select one such vertex like you did in your screenshot and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Similar > Amount of connecting Edges*

Exercise some caution as this will automatically select all vertex that belong only to two edges as the selected one. Be sure to inspect all the selected vertex to make sure no desirable corner vertex are mistakenly selected.

Then you can safely use <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertex* to delete the non-destructively

[image: Select Similar and dissolve]

Comment: This is a good solution.